# React native Image ' Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`. '

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

So this is my code
I already answered the question.

```
export const BigCard = ({Title, Image, Description}) => {
        console.log(Image)
            return(
                <StyledBigCard>
                    <StyledImage source={{
                        uri: Image,
                    }}/>
                    <StyledStroke>
                        <StyledStrokeText>
                            <StyledPBigCard>{Description}</StyledPBigCard>
                        </StyledStrokeText>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon style={style.icon} size={ 22 } icon={faChevronRight} />
                    </StyledStroke>
                </StyledBigCard>
        )
};
```

this is were i import the images etc. it is set in PBS1Detail, its an object so when i go to PBS1Detail.Image i get the image

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  
  const [PBS1Detail, setPBS1Detail] = useState([]);
  const [partnerLevel, setPartnerLevel] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=> {
      {/* DATABASE */}
  db.collection('Track').get().then((snapshot) => {
      let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      results.push(renderTracks(doc))
      }
    )
    setPBS1Detail(results)
    });
```

then i push it all the way to the screen were i import Image

all my imports are correct, and the console.log() gives me the good url to the image.
now when i now reload the app it gives the error "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`."
then when i update the image component to

```
<StyledImage source={{uri: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/image-parttime-bijbelschool-jaar-1/Track1Module1Thumbnail.jpg'}}
```

and than save the changes it works
then when i update it to

```
<StyledImage source={{uri: Image}} />
```

and than save the changes it also works

so when i run it the first time it gives me this error than when i change it to an url and than change it back to the Image prop it works. but when i reload the app it gives me this error again.

how can i fix this?

Comment: can you share a code snippet from the parent component where the Image prop is passed?

Comment: Are you using typescript in this project?

Comment: no i am not using typescript, i am using styled components

Comment: @imKrishh I have updated the question, console.log(Image) gives me a possitive result

Answer (score 0):

The `PBS1Detail` is an empty array until you actually get the image data from Firestore.

So when the first render, I guess you are trying to pass `undefined` or some invalid values for the source prop.

How about you give a condition for the render part?

```js
export const BigCard = ({Title, Image, Description}) => {
        console.log(Image)
            return(
                <StyledBigCard>
                
                    {!!Image && (
                      <StyledImage source={{
                          uri: Image,
                      }}/>
                    )}
                    
                    <StyledStroke>
                        <StyledStrokeText>
                            <StyledPBigCard>{Description}</StyledPBigCard>
                        </StyledStrokeText>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon style={style.icon} size={ 22 } icon={faChevronRight} />
                    </StyledStroke>
                </StyledBigCard>
        )
};
```

Comment: Wauw, the error was not from this code but it was a reausable component and on a different screen i send a wrong prop to it, thanx for the help, i will close the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not my code above, what i did was that on my homescreen i sended wrong props to Image is send

```
Image={Require('../../assets/Image.png')}
```

thats why te error occurded. i have set it to

```
Image={'https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/image-parttime-bijbelschool-jaar-1/Track1Module1Thumbnail.jpg'}
```

and it works perfectly!